# Workbook Scraper Issue

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I have been working on a workbook that scrapes data from hundreds of other workbooks and it works fine. However, when an error occurs, the workbook that has the error opens in the background and since this happens numerous times, my computer freezes before it can get through all the workbooks. Is there a way to suppress all link issue prompts and close workbooks that have errors instead of having them remain open? Here is the code that I have that works great for small sets of workbooks (I have done 10 without issue):

```
Sub CopyRange()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wkbDest As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
    Dim wkbSource As Workbook
    Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Dim LastRow As Long
  
    'you need to create this worksheet named "Log"
    Dim LogSheet As Worksheet
    Set LogSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log")
    
    Const strPath As String = "E:\Desktop\Example\"
        ChDir strPath
    strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    
    Application.StatusBar = "Importing Data..."
    
    Do While strExtension <> ""
        path = strPath & strExtension
        If VerifyTasks(strPath & strExtension, wkbDest) Then
            LogSheet.Range("A" & LogSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strPath & strExtension & "  " & "Succeeded"
        Else
            LogSheet.Range("A" & LogSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = strPath & strExtension & "  " & "Failed"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        strExtension = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
MsgBox "Data imported, review Log sheet."

End Sub

Function VerifyTasks(path As String, ByRef wkbDest As Workbook) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errorhandler:
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(path)
    With wkbSource
       'locate last row to start copying new value from the next spreadsheet
        LastRow = wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        'From the Basis & Credits cell AB46, copy to last row+1 in the Master sheet starting in row A2
        .Sheets("Basis & Credits").Range("AB46").Copy
         wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Range("A" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
    VerifyTasks = True
    Exit Function
errorhandler:
    VerifyTasks = False
End Function
```

Thank you.

Comment: Close the workbook on the errorhandler

Comment: How? I tried to use the code: `wkbSource.close savechanges:=False` and it didn't work.

Comment: I say that as I try again and it works just fine! Thank you for the help.